# Install CutyCapt on CentOS 6.3

Tags: centos

I am trying to install **[CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)** on CentOS 6.3

```
yum install Xvfb
yum install xorg-x11-fonts*
yum install subversion libqt4-webkit libqt4-dev
```

I am having problem in installing `libqt4-webkit` and `libqt4-dev`
I got this [**SO link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309446/trouble-installing-cutycapt-on-centos)
I tried out that solution but no help.
Please suggest me a way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those package names are for Debian-based systems, and you aren't on such a system. Use the equivalents for Red Hat-based systems instead. (Which they really should have provided for you so that I wouldn't have to look them up.)

```
yum install qtwebkit-devel qt-devel
```